# raise CacheMiss(record, field) odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(24,).raw

Tags: compiler-errors, odoo, odoo-14

raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(24,).raw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myxrdp/odoo14pos/odoo14-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 105, in _file_read
with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/myxrdp/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/Estate/b8/b8f9001425cfd0ef0315797909281b912817643a'

When Iam on multiprocessor on a instance after running login page ui is changed and this cache error is showing ...